# What does this error message mean 'pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Failed to parse string: ' ' as a scalar of type int64'?

Tags: compiler-errors, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, ipu

I'm trying to use the following hugging face optimum model (see : https://github.com/huggingface/optimumgraphcore/tree/main/examples/text-classification ) and train it using my own local dataset. My datasets are in .csv file format, and seem to be loading fine. However when I try to run the model using the following commands:

```
export TASK_NAME=mnli

python run_glue.py \
  --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased \
  --ipu_config_name Graphcore/bert-base-ipu \
  --train_file train.csv \
  --test_file test.csv \
  --validation_file validation.csv \
  --do_train \
  --do_predict \
  --max_seq_length 128 \
  --per_device_train_batch_size 32 \
  --pod_type pod4 \
  --learning_rate 2e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs 3 \
  --output_dir ./output/.../
```

I get the following error

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Failed to parse string: ' ' as a scalar of type int64

I'm pretty new to NLP, and just starting out so I'm not sure what I should be doing differently. My instinct is that my database isn't in the correct format, i.e. I'm trying to run an mnli task, and so I currently have my database columns split into 'premise' (text), 'hypothesis'(text) and 'label' (int), but I don't think that the model recognises the first two columns it as a string.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please post the full error stacktrace.

Comment: The error can be of two reason, first its expecting to have some string but ' ' is  empty. second update your package to latest one

Answer (score 2):

I once got the same error. You are trying to load data from an empty string, column or row in your csv file.
My own error was:
 `pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Failed to parse string: '/AfriSpeech-100/train/dcad6f05-bee3-4c85-80fc-4787878c02af/8c673b28f78868bb4b3ef4c060a1586b.wav' as a scalar of type double`

I corrected the path my code was looking at in my csv column and ensured that there was no null value in the column and everything worked fine afterwards.